# Vault invalid certificate or no client certificate supplied - cert auth method

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, pki, vault

I have created a CA in Vault to handle my certificate creation. I've followed this guide here: https://learn.hashicorp.com/vault/secrets-management/sm-pki-engine

I am trying to generate a client certificate using the pki secrets engine in Vault and then logging into Vault Using the cert auth method via this command:

vault login -address=https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8200 -tls-skip-verify -method=cert -ca-cert=cacert.pem -client-cert=cert.pem -client-key=key.key name=vaultclnt

The error I'm getting:

Error authenticating: Error making API request.

URL: PUT https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8200/v1/auth/cert/login
Code: 400. Errors:

- invalid certificate or no client certificate supplied

CERT INFO:

Certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----

Issuing CA
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----

CA chain
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIDqTCCApGgAwIBAgIUCGxptoHCke0n87cAY4FHamGo+ecwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEL
BQAwFjEUMBIGA1UEAxMLdmVyaXpvbi5jb20wHhcNMjAwNjA5MTYyNjIwWhcNMzAw
NjA3MTYyNjUwWjAWMRQwEgYDVQQDEwt2ZXJpem9uLmNvbTCCASIwDQYJKoZIhvcN
AQEBBQADggEPADCCAQoCggEBAMWs16u1gzycDqgaDYWRyeQqoQCnnvS+fJiMQ558
umfRq/03M7wZxnKbmw6qTIKjz/5wEleAhz3+ogViSdkgwashMExuognqudhpMQKL
uXIUetLoa8NYQ6C2TSb1ha7+Q3qzvfQpxOp4tfMI9Zr6Jctee9D3qKkYMaQtMIz+
eGKSj9U0AkVTKVeMUASMArAwvbwOHA4dCajZUpIQN5VS996j7PGDU/kx07bIGGCI
klbnx9CNXI5ZEGxy/lpeQNzsiautcTf0S4fyaxwj7m4MKd4erzK5+mpIS9IzERHf
IPfAvJKvnIoB4JpcE2hrap/MjGPj+wXr+iMI9qJwsMrpJFMCAwEAAaOB7jCB6zAO
BgNVHQ8BAf8EBAMCAQYwDwYDVR0TAQH/BAUwAwEB/zAdBgNVHQ4EFgQULKme72Cc
D/zEX5a4CsIBeg28XTwwHwYDVR0jBBgwFoAUmyRowx9E0bLThf6Y0o3dhHKamOgw
PAYIKwYBBQUHAQEEMDAuMCwGCCsGAQUFBzAChiBodHRwczovLzEyNy4wLjAuMTo4
MjAwL3YxL3BraS9jYTAWBgNVHREEDzANggt2ZXJpem9uLmNvbTAyBgNVHR8EKzAp
MCegJaAjhiFodHRwczovLzEyNy4wLjAuMTo4MjAwL3YxL3BraS9jcmwwDQYJKoZI
hvcNAQELBQADggEBAIsIycTrjSQeJCxUrjcMAzEQHN/K8ReBliStUTe/Y1MgUApx
ebR8jueuq8ZwJEhTgbSJFjymQ8BHdNWLEEXNeGJj3TwsgDm21c6jG/ZA/8nFqpT7
nob+uGeDTJeCoj07bJjOKGCGxkZfPK+u6fD7v7zYNVRlYHg5bHsgTrA3PlOgdeL4
aFXwRoqtRXcnvblb5VKig9Big2wpkCldDRGzfIcKVc02JsF5X3KNKQGHrL1Fdk38
X+qWBJ0VpbbnmIwR5Rk3wI437cyy/y3eyWs7LmXgOyA6JGfh4+8rIW+Br9+Nf6n2
QUf/v5dl2jvxwNtnnM2xoM1BdbZq6p7xKiIR1rg=
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

Private key
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

Private key type
rsa
Serial number
48:86:f5:7a:39:69:9a:cd:05:ab:19:b8:cd:96:86:92:bc:07:51:e7